# ¿Es posible recolectar datos de un input-text y transformarlos en una variable array usando JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: php, javascript, html

quiero saber si es posible tomar el valor que un usuario meta en un input-text y transformarlo en una variable Array, para después manipular esa variable. Si esto no es posible la pregunta cambia a: ¿Es posible con PHP?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action=" ">
 <input type="text" id="li">
  <!--El usuario ingresa valores tipo 5,3,2,1,4. Necesito que esos valores se almacenen  en una variable array en javaScript-->
 <script src="ju.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: si y si, cual es el objetivo final?

Comment: pues si se puede, tomar el valor del input y asignarlo a una variable. Si el usuario ingresa 5,3,2,1,4 y quieres que sea un arreglo podrias hacer un split a partir de la coma y manipular ese array que se genera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Declara una variable que será tu nuevo vector y que llenaremos con los valores separados por coma del texto que ingrese el usuario en el `input`
- Solo necesitas leer el valor del `input` y segmentarlo con `split`
- Una vez segmentado puedes rellenar una variable nueva con los valores separados por coma
- Hacemos uso de `push` para llenar el vector vacío con los valores del `input`
- La variable `vector` almacenará los números ingresados por el OP ahora con formato de *array*

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="texto" />
    <button id="button">Crear el vector</button>
    
    <script>
        let contenido = document.getElementById("texto")
        let button    = document.getElementById("button")
        let vector = []
        
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let valor = contenido.value.split(",")
          vector.push(valor)
          console.log(valor)
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez esto te ayude, ya que lo que hace es que cada vez que presiones una tecla, este acceda a una función para separar en un array todos los elementos separados por una coma (**,**)

```js
function convertir(){   
    var datos = document.getElementById('lista').value.split(',');
    console.log(datos);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lista" onkeyup="convertir()">
```

**Solo una Aclaracion muy importante:**

El *input* almacena cadenas por lo cual vas a tener que controlar que sean números y  convertir los valores para que puedas manipularlos como tal. Pero eso va depender mas de como lo quieras trabajar vos. Espero te ayude... Suerte!!!

Comment: Parece que lo editaste justo antes de que suba esta respuesta... Tienes mucho código que no aporta a tu pregunta... solo pon lo relevante ya que al parecer no muestras ni tus *inputs* que quieres ingresar

Answer (score 0):

Faltaría saber cual es la condición para el "después manipular esa variable", capturar el valor de un input dentro de un form es relativamente sencillo:

- engancharse al evento submit del form
- prevenir el submit ( el default del evento )
- recuperar el valor del input y agregarlo a un array
- no procesar el action del form retornando false

```js
var elInput = document.getElementById('li');
var elForm = document.getElementById('elform');
var elArray = [];


agregarAlArray = function(evento) {
  evento.preventDefault();
  elArray.push(elInput.value);
  console.log(elArray);
  return false;
}
elForm.addEventListener("submit", agregarAlArray, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id=elform>
    <input type=text id=li />
    <input type=submit value=agregar />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues verás esto es lo que quiero hacer, en lugar de tener que escribir el contenido de la variable lista en el código quiero que se pueda meter desde un input-text. Luego que se realice todo el código javascript. Osea quiero que únicamente la variable lista se llene con lo que el usuario escribió en el input-text convirtiendo el contenido en un array.

```js
//:::::::::::::::DATOS GENERALES::::::::::::::::
let lista=[34,28,20,17,44,54,94,84,23,13,15,66,19];
lista.sort(function(a,b){
 return a-b;
 });
let conteo_lista=lista.length;
let sumar_0=conteo_lista+1;
let Qi_Di_Pi=6;

//::::::ECUACIONES DE CUANTILES:::::::::::
let ecuacion_C=sumar_0*Qi_Di_Pi/4;
let aproximacion_C= Math.round(ecuacion_C);
let tomarvalores_C0= lista[aproximacion_C-1];
let tomarvalores_C1= lista[aproximacion_C-2];
let resultado_C=tomarvalores_C1+tomarvalores_C0;
resultado_C=resultado_C/2;


function cuantiles() {
 document.getElementById("G_text1").innerHTML="Lista de menor a mayor: "+lista+"<br>El resultado de la ecuación es: "+ecuacion_C;
 document.getElementById("C_0").style.display="inline";
 document.getElementById("C_1").style.display="inline";
}
function cuantiles1(){
 document.getElementById("resultado_G0").innerHTML="El resultado final es: "+resultado_C;

}
function cuantiles2(){
 document.getElementById("resultado_G0").innerHTML="El resultado final es: "+ tomarvalores_C0;
}

//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::DECILES:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
let ecuacion_D=sumar_0*Qi_Di_Pi/10;
let aproximacion_D= Math.round(ecuacion_D);
let tomarvalores_D0= lista[aproximacion_D-1];
let tomarvalores_D1= lista[aproximacion_D-2];
let resultado_D=tomarvalores_D1+tomarvalores_D0;
resultado_D=resultado_C/2;
console.log(aproximacion_D);

function deciles() {
 document.getElementById("G_text1").innerHTML="Lista de menor a mayor: "+lista+"<br>El resultado de la ecuación es: "+ecuacion_D;
 document.getElementById("D_0").style.display="inline";
 document.getElementById("D_1").style.display="inline";
}
function deciles1(){
 document.getElementById("resultado_G0").innerHTML="El resultado final es: "+resultado_D;

}
function deciles2(){
 document.getElementById("resultado_G0").innerHTML="El resultado final es: "+ tomarvalores_D0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1></h1>
 <h1></h1>
 <div>
  <button onclick="cuantiles();">Ci</button>
  <button onclick="deciles()">Di</button>
  <button onclick="">Pi</button>
  <h1 id="G_text1"></h1>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button onclick="cuantiles2()" class="entero" id="C_0">Numero entero</button>
  <button onclick="cuantiles1()" class="decimal" id="C_1">Numero decimal</button>
  <button onclick="deciles2()" class="entero" id="D_0">Numero entero o con decimal(0-4, 6,9)</button>
  <button onclick="deciles1()" class="decimal" id="D_1">Numero decimal(.5)</button>
  <button onclick="" class="entero" id="P_0">Numero entero</button>
  <button onclick="" class="decimal" id="P_1">Numero decimal</button>
  <h1 id="resultado_G0"></h1>
 </div>
 <script src="ca.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Camilo haz click en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/303222/edit) para agregar esta nueva información